# wxPython (wxWidgets): how to customize scrollbars look'n'feel?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, scrollbar, wxwidgets

I found examples for styling tabs (notebook), menus, windows, forms and many other but didn't see any example for scrollbars. Can anyoune show or prompt something about this?
I have idea about creating special wxPanel with slider and arrows but I don't know is it possible to hide system scrollbar and move content by dragging and clicking inside the pannel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the closest to what you are trying to do is `wx.lib.dragscroller`.

This is an example you find in wxPython demo from the official site:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.dragscroller

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def runTest(frame, nb, log):
    win = DragScrollerExample(nb, -1)
    return win

class DragScrollerExample(wx.ScrolledWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=-1):
        wx.ScrolledWindow.__init__(self, parent, id)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN, self.OnRightDown)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_UP, self.OnRightUp)

        self.SetScrollbars(1, 1, 2000, 2000, 0, 0)

        self.scroller = wx.lib.dragscroller.DragScroller(self)

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        self.DoPrepareDC(dc)

        pen = wx.Pen(wx.BLACK, 5)
        dc.SetPen(pen)

        for y in range(10):
            for x in range(10):
                dc.DrawCircle(x*400+20, y*400+20, 200)

        dc.DrawText('Right click and drag in the direction you want to scroll.',
                    20, 20)
        dc.DrawText('The distance from the start of the drag determines the speed.',                
                    20, 50)

    def OnRightDown(self, event):
        self.scroller.Start(event.GetPosition())

    def OnRightUp(self, event):
        self.scroller.Stop()


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

overview = """<html><body>
<h2>DragScroller</h2>
<p>
A helper class that adds scrolling to a wx.ScrolledWindow in the direction
of the drag.
</body></html>
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys,os
    import run
    run.main(['', os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])])
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful example. But now I can't find the right way to hide native scrollbars. When I try to use self.ShowScrollbars(wx.SHOW_SB_NEVER, wx.SHOW_SB_NEVER) in this code, the window content jumps back to start point when I click on it after dragging.

Comment: Hiding scrollbar could be tricky. if `wx.lib.dragscroller` is derived from `wx.ScrolledWindow` then it could be quite complicated. plz check this thread: http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Hiding-Scrollbars-td2308895.html

Comment: Yes, there is something to think about. But I guess this is the way.